# What is the difference between clauses 'temp table' vs 'global temporary table' in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, temp-tables

What is the difference between `CREATE TEMP TABLE myTempTable` and `CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE myTempTable` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in Postgres.  As the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) explains:

> The SQL standard also distinguishes between global and local temporary tables, where a local temporary table has a separate set of contents for each SQL module within each session, though its definition is still shared across sessions. **Since PostgreSQL does not support SQL modules, this distinction is not relevant in PostgreSQL.**
>
> For compatibility's sake, PostgreSQL will accept the GLOBAL and LOCAL keywords in a temporary table declaration, but **they currently have no effect**. Use of these keywords is discouraged, since future versions of PostgreSQL might adopt a more standard-compliant interpretation of their meaning.

I added the highlighting.

Comment: Is it means that 'create TEMP table' is just like write 'create LOCAL TEMPORARY table' ? Because from documentation above, it is comparing between GLOBAL temporary table and LOCAL temporary table, not between TEMP table and GLOBAL temporary table.

Comment: ... i guest TEMPORARY and TEMP are interchangeable clause. If GLOBAL not discribe that's means it's LOCAL ('create local [temp/temporary] table' equal to 'create [temp|temporary] table')

Comment: @FZS . . . Temporary tables are different from other tables (they are automatically deleted).  However, there is no distinction between global and local temporary tables.

Comment: `GLOBAL` and `LOCAL` are there because the `SQL` standard calls for them. Also to allow folks to migrate scripts from other `SQL` databases without them throwing a syntax error. In either case Postgres ignores them, so they have no practical effect. You can put them if you think your code is going to be run on another database that uses them. Just know their presence has no effect in Postgres.

Comment: @GordonLinoff about automatically deleted... if i created temp table, does anyone can use or see my temp table that i created ?

Comment: @FZS . . . Temporary tables are known only to the session that created them.  So, no, they are not visible to other users.